# How to use RealityKit's image AnchorEntity in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

I want to use RealityKit's AnchorEntity initialized with an Anchoring Component Target of type Image. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", 
                                        name: "imgAnchor"))
```

I have found zero documentation on how to use this.

Does anyone know the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AnchorEntity(.image(...))` in SwiftUI almost the same way as you used it in UIKit. At first click `Assets.xcassets` in Project Navigator pane and create `AR Resources` folder. Drag your image there. Setup its physical size in Inspector. Then copy/paste the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1))
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", 
                                          name: "image.png"))
        entity.setParent(anchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: There AR Resources folder is created by right clicking the Assets.xcassets under "AR and Textures" -> "New AR Resource Group". I could not find it quickly. (Xcode 13.3.)

Comment: Building this on the simulator will give the following (misleading error):
type 'AnchoringComponent.Target' has no member 'image'
The documentation does not show:
AnchorEntity(.image...)
I had to build it on the device for it to work. (Xcode 13.3.)

Comment: @Darkwonder, simulator can't activate image anchor. You need to use only REAL device in this case.

Comment: I know, its just I was reading the error and could not figure out why the project would not build. I have disconnected my iPhone from the mac and didn't see that the simulator was auto-selected. Been googling the issue, rather than just switching to the device. You wrote this somewhere before which saved me a lot of time without seeing such an stupid error message.

Comment: @AndyJazz can i add an anchor image that i already capture from a camera, not from the assets AR Resources ??

Comment: Hi @belalmedhat, I don't quite understand what exactly you want?

Comment: @AndyJazz what i mean is when i add image as anchor image like that                    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", name: "imgAnchor"))  the image already exists in my assets, but what i'm trying to achieve is, for example, open app that have camera access and capture image of an object, for example, a (business card) and use that business card image as my anchor ??

Comment: Here's some helpful stuff on the subject – https://www.netguru.com/blog/on-device-training-with-core-ml-make-your-pancakes-healthy-again

Comment: So, you basically need two things: 1) on-device ML training and 2) a combination of two coordinate systems for image anchor positioning.